# Crear un nuevo proyecto en Symfony 3 : Error creating resource : Failed to enable crypto

Tags: symfony3

Quiero crear un nuevo Symfony proyecto pero encuentro un problema cuando utiliso el comando `php symfony.phar new Symfony`

Utiliso Ubuntu 16.04

```
/var/www$ php symfony.phar new Symfony



  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]                                      
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Failed to enable crypto          
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 406                                                                   
  [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open st  
  ream: operation failed                                                       
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 406                                                                   
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header                           
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 407                                                                   






  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]                                    
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Failed to enable crypto          
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 406                                                                   
  [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open st  
  ream: operation failed                                                       
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 406                                                                   
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header                           
  [file] phar:///var/www/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/St  
  reamHandler.php                                                              
  [line] 407
```

Me diga una persona modificar el read-only fichero /etc/php.ini y decomente la línea siguiente

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es esto : debemos modificar el read-only fichero /etc/php.ini y decomentar la línea siguiente

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Tadam!